# Selenium not scrolling to the very bottom of google maps to fetch reviews

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following code to scroll down to the 100th page of my google maps but the scroll is actually not working. It just returns the first 10 reviews that means only the first scroll is working fine. Any suggestions as to how this can be resolved?

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
       # we now need to click on the xxxxx reviews option
       driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]/div[2]/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(1)
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5  # Reduced pause time for demonstration; adjust as needed

 # Click the 'xxxxx reviews' option to open the reviews section
try:
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]/div[2]/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(1)  # Short pause to ensure the reviews section is open
except NoSuchElementException:
print("Could not find the reviews button. Please check the XPath.")

# Initialize variables for scrolling logic
number_of_scrolls = 0
max_scrolls = 10  # Maximum number of scroll actions you want to perform

while number_of_scrolls < max_scrolls:
# Scroll action
try:
    ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[10]')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 200);', ele)  # Reduced scroll amount to 1000 pixels
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Scroll element not found. Please check the XPath.")
    break

time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)  # Wait for the page to load more content

# Increase the scroll counter
number_of_scrolls += 1
print(f'Scroll #{number_of_scrolls} completed.')

print("Finished scrolling through the reviews.")
```